# MongoDB Tree Structure Multiple Parents, sum and multiply

Tags: mongodb, tree, graph-databases, aggregation

I am trying to build a bill of materials mini-app.

The heirarchy image below shows how there are a number of assemblies (the 110 numbers) with one or more parts (100 numbers) or assemblies nested below them.

[Bill of materials heirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqcZs.png)

Currently my data is structured like this:

```
collection.insert({'part_project': 998,
                   'part_number': 002,
                   'part_category_prefix': 1,
                   'part_type': 110,
                   'part_description': 'Tier 2 Assembly B',
                   'part_revision': 1,
                   'part_version': 'A',
                   'bill_of_material_usages': [{
                       'bom_version': 'A',
                       'part_version': 'A',
                       'part_revision': 1,
                       'children': [
                           {'part_number': '998 1 3 100', 'quantity': 3},
                           {'part_number': '998 1 4 110', 'quantity': 1}
                       ]}]
                   })
```

There is an array called 'bill_of_material_usages' which stores information about the part or assembly's children and the versions referenced.

I'm trying to figure out how to then represent this in a table where each assembly lists all of its parts and sub-assemblies.

I'm also trying to figure out how to add up total quantities of a part. That means if Assembly A has 2 of Assembly B and Assembly B has 3 of Part A then there will be a total of 2*3=6 Part A's.

Any advice on how to do this with the current data structure or a better structure would be fantastic.

I'm currently using MongoDB, Flask, vis.js and google charts.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a recursive function that follows a children branch of the tree until the last child has no further children. This allows me to build a structured tree and to calculate the total number of instances of an individual part.

Recursive functions are limited by the number of recursions possible (think inception) although this limitation is unlikely to have an impact for my use-case.

Comment: In newer versions of MongoDB, you might be able to use [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup) for this.